# How do I append SQL statements within a cursor using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I am trying to execute the following script (**SQL Server 2008**) but it seems that the first portion of the script is always missing when I do the final `PRINT(@sql)` at the bottom. Am I somehow overwriting the first portion of the script?

I think the issue is with declaring the `@sql` variable within the `CURSOR`. When I move the declaration above the `OPEN @tableCursor` I receive different output. What is the implication of setting the `@sql` variable within a table cursor?

```
OPEN @tableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @tableCursor INTO @constituentId, @internalName, @fieldName, @value
WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN

SET @sql = ''
IF (@fieldName = 'MARKET_SECTOR_DES')
BEGIN
-- this is the section that is missing when I do the PRINT(@sql) below
SELECT @sql = @sql + '
    -- Update BloombergMarketSector
    UPDATE dbo.Constituent
    SET BloombergMarketSector = ''' + @value + ''',
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE id = ' + @constituentId + '
    '
PRINT (@sql) -- this works
END

PRINT (@sql) -- this works - it seems the issue is happening with this SELECT statement
SELECT @sql = @sql + '              
    -- Update the Column                
    -- The Column Exists - update
    IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM dbo.ConstituentBloombergAttribute AS cba
                WHERE cba.ConstituentId = ' + @constituentId + ')
    BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO dbo.ConstituentBloombergAttribute (ConstituentId, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)
        VALUES (' + @constituentId + ', ''admin'', GETDATE(), ''admin'', GETDATE())                     
    END

    UPDATE dbo.ConstituentBloombergAttribute
    SET ' + @internalName + ' = ''' + @value + ''',
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ConstituentId = ' + @constituentId + '
    '

PRINT @sql
FETCH NEXT FROM @tableCursor INTO @constituentId, @internalName, @fieldName, @value
END
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SET`?

Comment: @AbeMiessler I did actually and I noticed the same thing. I'll try it again to be certain though.

Comment: are you sure `@fieldName = 'MARKET_SECTOR_DES'`?

Comment: @Hogan Yes. I put in a simple `PRINT 'HI'` and I saw that being printed.

Comment: Note that if `NULL` is anywhere in any concatenation, the entire thing becomes `NULL`, so that's likely not it.  Can you do `print(@fieldName); print(@sql)` right before `END` in the `IF` clause, and reply with the output?

Comment: @mellamokb Ah - when I do the `PRINT(@sql)` right before (or after) the `END` the text shows up. What does this mean? Is it concatenation or possibly scope or something else? It seems the issue is the next `SET @sql = ` statement.

Comment: Approximately how big is the entire string, i.e., what size is `@constituentId`, `@value`, and `@internalName`?  Like < 1000 characters total?  What is the declared max size of `@sql`?  Can you provide some example values for all of these variables in a self-contained [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: `@DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)` and the entire string doesn't seem large enough to cause an issue. It's two `UPDATE` statements and an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: It can matter, because [`PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) will only print up to 8,000 characters of the string, but I believe it is the beginning, not the end.  And I agree, your string doesn't look near that big unless `@value` is 7,000 characters or something like that.  Can you give us the exact values of all variables so it's possible to run the entire script ourselves?

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7902.  It works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables is null, try this:

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + '
    -- Update BloombergMarketSector
    UPDATE dbo.Constituent
    SET BloombergMarketSector = ''' + isnull(@value,'V MISSING') + ''',
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE id = ' + isnull(@constituentId,'C MISSING') + '
    '
```

Could be a database setting: When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON, concatenating a null value with a string yields a NULL result. For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL yields NULL. When SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is OFF, concatenating a null value with a string yields the string itself (the null value is treated as an empty string). For example, SELECT 'abc' + NULL yields abc.

Comment: The only problem with this idea is that if any of the variables are `null`, it would make everything `null`. So the final result of `@sql` should be `null`, not half of the complete statement.

Comment: @mellamokb You are right, the code in the question is inaccurate or incomplete.

Comment: The variables are not `null` but this is a good suggestion to point out. If I put in a `PRINT (@sql)` before or after the `END` it prints out the correct statement. I think the problem is with that `SELECT` statement but I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I will do this shortly when I am on my other computer. I'm thinking now - could this be due to `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` being set to `ON`? I'm pretty sure it's set to `ON` but I'll post the full code soon.

Comment: @IanO'Brien See my edit on CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL database setting. Run EXEC sp_configure to see your configurations.

Comment: I updated the code. The script is inside of a cursor and I think this makes a difference. When I moved the `DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)` above the cursor it printed the values correctly, but with some spaces between the lines. Is there some issue with scope and a `CURSOR`?